# Can't run DynaForm - BUILD FAILED - Ant

Tags: ant

To run the sample application of DynaForm (a dynamic web form generator) I followed the readme instruction:

> DynaForm - a dynamic web form genrator
>
> To run the sample application use your command line and type "ant".
> Then open localhost:2000/ on your browser.
>
> The build script requires ANT and JDK (at least Java 1.6) to be in the path.
>
> The DynaForm's project site is hostet at:
> http://code.google.com/p/xsd-web-forms/
>
> Rein Raudjärv
> May 23 2010

In my Mac I have ANT and JDK (with Java 1.6). When launch in my command line "ant" I have this error:

> BUILD FAILED
> /Users/colet/Desktop/dynaform/build.xml:64: /Users/colet/Desktop/dynaform/${env.ANT_HOME}/lib does not exist.

Maybe I misunderstood the sentence:

> The build script requires ANT and JDK (at least Java 1.6) to be in the path.

what does "to be in the path" mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please clone the DynaForm project from GitHub instead of Google Code:
https://github.com/reinra/dynaform

The newer version builds via Maven instead of Ant, so it's simpler and should work better.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have defined `ANT_HOME` environment variable correctly. Refer to [Ant installation instructions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html), if needed.